# Как с помощью PHPSessID получить user_id

Tags: php, yii2

На моем сайте авторизовался пользователь. Ему в куку записался PHPSESSID.

Как, зная этот PHPSESSID, сервер может сказать, авторизован пользователь или нет?
В какой переменной хранится эта информация?

Авторизация проходит встроенными средствами yii2.

Например:

Пользователь зашел на сайт. Зарегистрировался и авторизовался. Ему в куку записался `PHPSESSID = 6g7a6m1prd3sdd4batr735cdl0`. Пользователь увидел эту куку и передал мне. 
Могу ли я узнать с помощью данного `PHPSESSID`, а именно `6g7a6m1prd3sdd4batr735cdl0` узнать кто сидит под этой комбинации на сервере?

Как это можно сделать?

`$_SESSION['6g7a6m1prd3sdd4batr735cdl0']` ничего не даст
`$session = new Session; $session->open(); $session['6g7a6m1prd3sdd4batr735cdl0']` тоже.
И это видимо логично. Ведь _SESSION принадлежит к определенной данной сессии, а не доступ ко всем сессиям сервера.

Куда мне обратиться, чтобы получить информацию по этой сессии?

Comment: Вы хотите получить именно `ID` сессии? Если да, то попробуйте `Yii::$app->session->getId();` Сессия начинается при входе в проект. Соответственно, если Вы хотите проставить триггер вошёл пользователь или нет - Вам необходимо в сессию его добавить, чтобы работать с ним дальше.

Comment: не совсем понял, кого "его"?

Comment: Триггер(метку).

Comment: `попробуйте Yii::$app->session->getId()` я знаю его SESSID. Мне необходимо получить информацию об этой сессии. Как это сделать?

Comment: может есть что-то типа `$_SESSION['abrakadabra']` ?

Comment: Почти. `$session['name'] = $value;` https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-session

Comment: Видимо я очень плохо объясняю(( Обновил вопрос

Comment: хранилище сессий то какое? файлы если, то ищите файл во временной папке (или где настроено) с этим идентификатором. можете его открыть и извлечь данные оттуда, очевидно, в данных сессии будет нужный вам id. Если хранилище не файловое, а БД например и т.п. логика та же.

Comment: Т.е. средствами Php это сделать нельзя?

Comment: почему ж нельзя. из консоли у вас будет достаточно прав чтобы прочитать файл сессии, десериализовать его.

Comment: В yii2 же можно указать, какой тих хранилища использовать. Думал может есть готовая надстройка и для моей задачи.

Comment: ваша задача вообще не типична, мягко говоря, и в целом может быть применена либо для какой-то отладки администратором, либо злоумышленником, который имеет доступ к серверу. На кой еще это может понадобится не ясно. Для отладки собственно можно просто файл сессии открыть в блокноте и посмотреть что там, если сессия не шифрована. Зачем вам тут cli не особо то и понятно. 
Что вы вообще делаете-то?

Comment: Есть сайт 1 : domain.ru. На нем пользователь производит авторизацию. 
Есть сайт 2 sub.domain.ru. 
У наших сайтов общие куки. 
При заходе на сайт 2 я хочу передать сайту 1 куку PHPSESSID, и он смог мне ответить авторизован ли пользователь или нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yii::$app->user->isGuest;
```

Посмотрите документацию для более подробной информации: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли вопрос. Как в консоли узнать авторизован ли пользователь с таким PHPSESSID?

Comment: Под "Консоль" вы имеете ввиду средствами js?

Comment: я имею ввиду PHP_CLI

Answer (score 0):

Вы пошли по правильному пути, но чуть чуть не дожали. Вам нужно сделать так:
Yii::$app->session->setId('6g7a6m1prd3sdd4batr735cdl0');
$sessionData = (array)Yii::$app->session;

В переменной sessionData будет массив данных сессии. Там есть ключ _id в котором хранится идентификатор пользователя.
НО! Если вы делаете это в консольных коммандах, то там вообще не будет компонента session. Для того чтоб был, вам надо скопировать конфиг компонентов user и session.

Если вы хотите получить данные сессии без йии в консоли, то надо сделать так:
session_start();
session_id('6g7a6m1prd3sdd4batr735cdl0');
$sessionData = $_SESSION;

И тут есть опять "НО". Дело в том, что если вы попытаетесь так прочитать сессию, созданную йии, то скорее всего получите билеберду, так как сессия скорее всего зашифрована, но это не точно.

И еще обратите внимание на то где хранится сессия. Если в не стандартном хранилище, то второй вариант не сработает.

Comment: _"Если указан параметр id, то он заменит идентификатор текущий сессии. Для этого session_id() следует вызывать до session_start(). "_